# Two div re sizable opposite to each other

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, resizable

I want to make two div resizable vertically. for example

**Top div height is 400px and Bottom div height is 200. When I've resize bottom div 250px then top div height should be 350px.**

I've using jQuery UI resizable:

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/qhazak3t/)

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".dv-bottom").resizable({
            handles: {
              'n': '.handle'
            }
          }).on("resize", function(event, ui) {
            $('.dv-bottom').height(600 - ui.size.height);
            $('.dv-top').css({
              top: '0'
            });;
          });
        });
```

```html
<div class="dv-top">
</div>
<div class="dv-bottom">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n handle"></div>

  <div class=" pane-content">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this on resize:

```
hBottom = ui.size.height
$('.dv-bottom').height(hBottom).css('top',0);
hTop = 600 - hBottom;
$('.dv-top').height(hTop);
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofem40cf/